# Ember: Local config for development

Tags: ember.js

I want to share my ember-project between all members in my team.
Since every development environment is different (OS, VM for server, etc.) I thought it would be best practice to hold an local-environmen-file in each repository clone which will be ignored by git and just holds the specific config of each team-member.

For Example in my app the application adapter holds the "host:" entry which is a computed-property which uses the local-environment-file and reads the IP of the server (where to connect to).

My current approach looks like that:

```
// ./config/localenv.js

module.exports = function() {
  var LOCALENV = {

    host: "http://192.168.1.44:3000"

  };

  return LOCALENV;
};
```

And Im importing it in my adapter like that:

```
// ./app/pods/application/adapter.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import LOCALENV from 'your-application-name/config/localenv';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  host: Ember.computed(function() {
    return LOCALENV.host;

  })

});
```

Unfortunately ember returns error logs in the browser console (the referenced/imported module was not found...). What am Im doing wrong?

Comment: To be honest, I can't see what could be going wrong here, unlelss there's a typo in the path to localenv.  Alternatively you could try a relative path to it and see if that makes any difference.

One other trick I use to see if a file is being picked up at all is to add a console.log before the exports, at the top level of the file.  That's another thing you could try.

Comment: Also remember that you will need to call LOCALENV like it's a function, because you'll be importing its function.  So you'll need to call `LOCALENV().host`

Comment: If you take a look at the way that app.js imports its config, you can see it uses a path relative to the root of `app`.  See line 4:

`import config from './config/environment';`